# Fuse filesystem that supports access to FTP

Tags: ftp, filesystems, libcurl, fuse

I have to implement a filesystem that supports access to FTP using fuse, and add support for commands such as ls,cp. I have made a simple hello cpp program that uses fuse along with implementing getaddr,readdir, read and write functions. What should I do next?.How can I mount FTP server and make it connected with fuse?

Answer (score 1):

You should go over the basic ftp command and see how they match fuse file operations. Some basic examples:

- In fuse init you should do the connection to the ftp server
- In fuse open and write calls you should call ftp put
- In fuse open and read calls you should call ftp get
- In fuse opendir , ftp cd

etc etc... 
good luck